# How to get load file under resources folder in scala sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, properties-file, akka-actor

I am having a akka actors config file under resources,

```
src/main/resources/remote_app.conf
src/main/scala/actors/Notification.scala
```

I am loading the resources as below,

1.

```
val configFile = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("remote_app.conf").getFile
val config_mediation = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFile))
actorSystem = ActorSystem("MediationActorSystem", config_mediation)
```

2.

```
val path = getClass.getResource("/remote_app.conf").getFile
val config_mediation = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(path))
actorSystem = ActorSystem("MediationActorSystem", config_mediation)
```

Both works fine when i execute from main program and getting the below logs,

> [INFO] [11/21/2016 21:05:02.835] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started;
>   listening on addresses
>   :[akka.tcp://MediationActorSystem@127.0.0.1:7070] [INFO] [11/21/2016
>   21:05:02.838] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses:
>   [akka.tcp://MediationActorSystem@127.0.0.1:7070]

I am creating a jar using sbt test:assembly and executing the main class as below
SBT:

```
resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value /"src/main/resources"
resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value /"src/main/resources"

java -cp <jar> <args>
```

Its not able to load the config file when i execute from jar.
Anything am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is the popular program encountered by lot of people. Use `getResourceAsStream` This works normally and when used inside jar.

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/remote_app.conf")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This getResourceAsStream  gives the input stream `getClass.getResourceAsStream("/remote_app.conf")` . This ConfigFactory `val config_mediation = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(path))` does not have support to parse input stream . Is there any way i can do this.. parse string is there or parse reader

Answer (score 1):

Answer from pamu is a nice hint but did not fully work for me. You still have to convert it to an `InputStream`.
The full solution would be:

```
val is = getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("remote_app.conf")
val source = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to use something like lightbend conf -library:
https://github.com/lightbend/config

It will by default pick the application.conf file from -resources folder.

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
```

You can also give the load -function other file names as parameter:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load("someother.conf")
```

Note: no slash before filename.